# Aspas Simples vs. Duplas em PHP Regex

Tags: php, string, regex, preg-match

Considerando que possuo um `path` cujo qual desejo verificar com `preg_match` se é o caminho desejado, qual a diferença entre as duas operações a seguir?

```
// Single quoted string
preg_match('/\/path\/to\/folder\//', $path)

// Double quoted string
preg_match("/\/path\/to\/folder\//", $path)
```

Supondo também uma string qualquer:

```
// Single quoted string
preg_match('/some\\\\string/', $string)

// Double quoted string
preg_match("/some\\\\string/", $string)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [resposta do Ivcs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/159537/14213) explica muito bem a parte das aspas, apenas complementando do ponto que gera seu problema.

#### Problema

- Você tem um duplo problema aqui: `"/\/path\/to\/folder\//"`.
- E apenas um aqui `'/\/path\/to\/folder\//'`.

#### O que você deseja

- Encontrar o `path`, `/path/to/folder/`.

#### Explicação

- **1º problema:** Se trata da própria montagem da RegEx, pois você esta usando como "fronteiras" o `/`. Assim toda vez que você quiser usar um `/` literal no RegEx, vai ter que escapar para não ser interpretado como fim da expressão, logo precisa de `\/` quando aspas simples `'` e `\\/` quando aspas duplas `"`.
- **2º problema:** Dentro de aspas duplas, o `\` é um caractere de escape, então tudo que vier depois de `\` sera convertido para literal. 
  Assim sua regex que era `"/\/path\/to\/folder\//"` vai virar `"//path/to/folder//"` gerando um erro na compilação da RegEx.

#### Soluções

1. Manter a fronteira `/` e escapar cada `\`: `"/\\/path\\/to\\/folder\\//"`
2. Alterar para aspa simples, assim ele não interpreta o `\` como escape da string e sim como literal: `'/\/path\/to\/folder\//'`
3. Usar outro caractere de fronteira, como `~`, note que aqui você ainda tem `\` como escape da string: `"~\/path\/to\/folder\/~"`

#### Resumindo tudo

```
'~/path/to/folder/~'
```

- Aqui você não tem que escapar os caracteres iguais às fronteiras.
- Aqui a `/` não precisa ser escapada com `\`.

Comment: Cara, perfeito, explica exatamente o que será o RegEx e ainda de brinde um Good Practice.

Answer (score 3):

Usar aspas simples ou duplas vem da linguagem PHP, geralmente as características delas são:

Aspas duplas:

- um pouco mais lentas, pois, tenta processar dados
- lê variáveis entro dela, exemplo: "oi $nome"
- permite caracteres de escape, como: "oi\noutra linha"

Aspas simples:

- um pouco mais rápida, pois é tratada como string, independentemente se há escape ou variáveis presente nela.

A única diferença que pode ocorrer é que dando aspas simples você não terá o carácter e escape '\', então seria mais seguro usar aspas duplas.

No primeiro exemplo:

```
// Single quoted string
preg_match('/\/path\/to\/folder\//', $path)

// Double quoted string
preg_match("/\/path\/to\/folder\//", $path)
```

Seria:

```
/\/path\/to\/folder\//

//path/to/folder//
```

Resumindo, o PHP tratará a string de acordo com as aspas usada, na primeira nada muda pois ele não realiza nenhum tratamento, como o segundo é entre aspas simples, há tratamento, que no caso seria os caracteres de escapes, entao a string ficaria da forma passada anteriormente.